# How to develop a program which understands context of the message?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, siri

I know this question is going to be open ended, but since I do not have much experience in the field, I find StackOverflow the only place to ask this question:

I am trying to build a server side application which would be able to take user queries and give some answers. For example some of the basic queries would be what is the weather in my location or give me directions to this place? I have just few limited queries which I would like it to process. Are there some existing APIs or technologies I could use which could help me do the same? IBM Watson has a lot of machine learning capabilities but I am not sure if it could help me. (With related to weather, I might just have questions like weather today or weather this week, weather in some other city. I just would want to know which of these options my program should query)

I know this sounds like building a Siri or Google Now, but I just wanted to know if there are certain technologies I could use to help me or some information on how I should tackle this problem.

Comment: There's no short answer to this; you need to read up on question answering. Why don't you start with the [Wikipedia article on the topic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_answering) and follow some of the sources.

Comment: do you need an API to help you in processing the question or providing answers?

Comment: @Mehdi processing the question. I can call the google maps api or weather api

Comment: take a look as facebook's new product: https://wit.ai/

Comment: @Mehdi looks Interesting. I shall read more about this and check if it will help me out. Thanks!

Comment: @Mehdi Thanks for introducing me wit.ai ! It's awesome!!